# How to stop an element that is position:fixed from overlapping static positioned elements

Tags: html, css, position, positioning, overlapping

I am a beginner when it comes to CSS positioning.

My problem:
I am attempting to create an element that contains links to social networking sites. I want this element to be "position:fixed;" so it does not scroll, I also want it to have a margin between my #social div (the element that I am trying to get to do this) and #bodycontainer div (which contains the rest of my website) - I do not want the margin referencing off the browser window (but based off of the #bodycontainer div.

Basically I want to:

- Disallow the #social div from overlapping #bodycontainer (rest of website), yet keeping #social 's position: fixed.
- Keep a margin between #social and #bodycontainer. I do not want to base the margin off the browser window, I want it to be based off my #bodycontainer div. How do I do this? (I want #social to be 5px to the left of #bodycontainer.

My code (shortened):

```
 <body>

<div id="social">

<div id="socialimages">
<a href="http://facebook.com/connor.lydon" target="_blank">
<img src="fblogo.gif">
</a>
<a href="http://instagram.com/connorlydon" target="_blank">
<img src="instalogo.gif">
</a>
</div>
</div>




<div id="bodycontainer">
<img src="lydon_websiteanimation.gif" id="header">
</div>

</body>


#social {
position: fixed;
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
margin-left: 10px;
background-image: url(socialtalk.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top-left;
}

#socialimages {
width: 45px;
height: 100px;
margin-left: 200px;
margin-top: 60px;
}

#bodycontainer {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 726px;
}
```

I am guessing that this is quite a simple question, and I apologize. I have looked at many guides and have been having trouble figuring it out on my own.

If you would like to rephrase part of my question so you can better understand it then please say - I gladly will!

I greatly appreciate any help I will receive.

Thank you.

Comment: I cant see your problem could you use http://jsfiddle.net/h9FqE/ to show illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <body>

<div id="social">

<div id="socialimages">
<a href="http://facebook.com/connor.lydon" target="_blank">
<img src="fblogo.gif">
</a>
<a href="http://instagram.com/connorlydon" target="_blank">
<img src="instalogo.gif">
</a>
</div>
</div>




<div id="bodycontainer">
<img src="lydon_websiteanimation.gif" id="header">
</div>

</body>


#social {
position: fixed;
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
margin-left: 10px;
background-image: url(socialtalk.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top-left;
}

#socialimages {
width: 45px;
height: 100px;
margin-left: 200px;
margin-top: 60px;
}

#bodycontainer {
width: 726px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -363px;
z-index: 1;
}
```